# Could the existence of God be just a matter of perspective?

Tags: theology, quantum-physics, atheism, universe

For most of my life, I was an atheist because the idea of God just seemed illogical and I felt a complete inability to believe what religious people would say considering the lack of evidence and huge amounts of contradictions.

Later as I thought about it, I figured the zero-point energy field could be God. That seems to fit with known science and commonly believed theories. It would mean the big bang theory is correct, as the universe is just a giant quantum fluctuation. It would also kind of mean evolution is God too (or simply God's method of creation) because what is evolution? It's simply the changes that happen due to quantum fluctuations. This would make God all-powerful because despite the zero-point energy field having total energy of zero, it still controls infinite forces.

For it to be accurate to define the zero-point energy field as God though, it would be required for the radiation given off from quantum fluctuations to survive outside of space-time, as that would contain all information, past present and future. The information would also need to be processed and used at some point in history, including any time in the future. For example, in a quadrillion years, the universe could form a giant brain using dark matter (may have to be dark matter to process infinite information because its density is also infinite) to make the precise calculations necessary to generate a quantum fluctuation to produce the universe we are in.

I can think of a few logical statements that seem to confirm that what I have said is true but the same statements also seem to confirm that what I have said is not true. It's like God both exists and does not exist at the same time, and the answer to the question, "Does God exist?", is it's just a matter of perspective or even, it's real if you believe it, it's not if you don't. It doesn't apply to most peoples' definition of God though because a God from fairy tales that can break the laws of physics is completely paradoxical. The following show what I mean:

1. All possibilities happen. This means the universe would just be created by chance, with there being no need for God to exist. Surely, this would also mean my definition of God can also be described as a possibility, so therefore God also exists.
2. The radiation given off from quantum fluctuations exists for zero seconds. It's impossible for the radiation given off from quantum fluctuations to not exist for at least zero seconds, regardless of whether it exists or not. If it exists for exactly zero seconds, that's the same as not existing, meaning the soul of God doesn't exist and God doesn't exist. Considering it's outside of space-time, then if all possibilities happen, it is the soul of God and God does exist because existing for just zero seconds is enough for it to be real outside of spacetime.
3. The total energy is zero, therefore nothing is there so there can't be God. Minus infinity plus infinity equals zero. We are talking about infinite forces that created the universe. How can something all-powerful not be described as God?

Considering the total energy of our universe is precisely zero, in a way our universe doesn't really exist as anything more than a possibility, and the only reason it's real is that being a possibility is what makes it real. Is the same not true about God when defined as a possibly God making it a possibility?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132178/discussion-on-question-by-dan-bray-could-the-existence-of-god-be-just-a-matter-o).

Comment: Please be aware that questions and answers are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Anything closed can be edited to bring it within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [MetaPhil](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> For it to be accurate to define the zero point energy field as God though, it would be required for the radiation given off from quantum fluctuations to survive outside of space time, as that would contain all information, past present and future. The information would also need to be processed and used at some point in history, including any time in the future.

There is no such thing as "outside of space time," or at the very least, not under our current theories of physics. The geometry of spacetime is rather complicated, but suffice it to say, all currently accepted theories of physics are [local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality), unless you go *well* off the beaten path into very strange iterations of physics such as [de Broglie-Bohm theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory), which is technically compatible with observation, but widely disliked specifically because of its nonlocality. This includes fields such as the vacuum field, which are typically defined as having specific values at specific points in spacetime, and propagating at or (rarely) below the speed of light.

If you want to refer to objects or physical effects persisting "outside of spacetime," you need to define exactly what you mean by that, because mainstream physics has no notion of such a thing.

Comment: If you said it's mathematically impossible to even perceive actual consciousness as having any kind of awareness, proves that outside space time is mathematically impossible.

Does the above sound like I'm contradicting my own theory? I am clearly perceiving consciousness, which is enough to be certain that being able to perceive it is real.

Simply perceiving consciousness is literally a mathematical impossibility. This seams like a massive contradiction as, I am sure you can perceive actual consciousness. It still makes no sense mathematically. How can opposite outcomes even be true?

Comment: @DanBray: I never said anything about perceiving or consciousness, so I do not understand what the first sentence of your comment is intended to mean. I am therefore unable to follow the rest of it, either.